# c++ select async programming

Tags: c++, select, asynchronous

Is there a way to have 'select' waiting for reads and writes, while also being able to add new file descriptors? Preferrably on one thread?

Comment: If you only have one thread, then who is adding the new file descriptors?

Comment: @Oli: I think OP just wants to cancel the `select` call and add the descriptor before another call to `select` is made.

Comment: @Andre: But with only one thread, *when* does he want to break the `select`?  Is there some external stimulus?

Comment: @Oli: Well I'm actually using sockets. So more clients may be connecting.

Comment: @Andrew: But presumably your listening socket is part of that select, so when a new client connects the select *does* return, allowing you to change the fd set for the next call.

Comment: @Greg: I didn't realize that select would return when you get a new client. This DEFINATELY clears things up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I know what your scenario is (a socket-based server that may want to accept new incoming connections), did you know that you can append the file-descriptor for your listening socket to the list for `select`?  See e.g. http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html.

(Paraphrased example:)

```
fd_set socks;

FD_ZERO(&socks);

// Add listener socket
listen(sock, n);
FD_SET(&socks, sock);

// Add existing socket connections
for (i = 0; i < num_existing_connections; i++)
{
    FD_SET(&socks, connection[i]);
}

// Will break if any of the existing connections are active,
// or if a new connection appears.
select(..., &socks, ...);
```

Comment: The website was VERY helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I think, You can do it in same thread but not at the same time. In a problem like this I normally add my dummy loop-back socket in the descriptor list and whenever I have to add a new socket in FD_LIST, I just send a byte to my dummy socket and it breaks the Select Loop. Then I can update the FD_LIST and resume with the select again.

Comment: You can also add a timeout to the `select` call using the last parameter.

Comment: Yes of course. But in that case if you are using long time interval in select then you have to wait until your new socket is added to the FD_LIST. If you are using very short interval in select or you don't need to add socket immediately then using the interval parameter is good option.