# Terminating C program on command line, but make sure writer is finished writing

Tags: c, file, file-writing

I have a C server that writes packet data to an output file. The problem is I terminate the server in terminal using control c, and I've noticed that my output file is never finished writing to. Is there a way to make sure that my output file is completely written to before quitting?

(I know I could just let the server run longer so I'm sure the data I want has been written, but I'm looking for an alternative method)

Thanks

Here's my code for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int PORT_NUM = 0; 
int RecordRate = 3000; 

typedef struct timeval timeval;
timeval time_;


void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[1000000];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     FILE *fp;

     PORT_NUM = atoi(argv[1]);  
     fp = fopen(argv[2],"w");   

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
            error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     //portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     portno = PORT_NUM;
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,10);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
            error("ERROR on accept");

    int counter = 0;    
    int total_bytes_sent = 0;

     while(1){  

         bzero(buffer,1000000);
         n = read(newsockfd,buffer,999999);

         if (n < 0) {
             error("ERROR reading from socket");
         }
         else if (n != 0) {
             total_bytes_sent += n;
             gettimeofday(&time_, NULL);

             if(counter%RecordRate==0){
             printf("counter  %d \n", counter); 
             fprintf(fp,"\"%d\",\"%ld\",\"%d\",\"%d\",\"%d\"\n", counter, time_.tv_sec, time_.tv_usec, n,total_bytes_sent);
             }

             counter++; 

             //print format: packet number, time Sec, time milli Sec, bytes in packet, total bytes sent 
            // example: "11182","1465921447","196422","3100","26821100"

         }
     }
     fclose(fp);
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
     }
```

Comment: One option would be to do an `fflush()` after doing an output so that any file output buffers that are hold data will be flushed to the output file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming  This may decrease performance slightly since it overrides the operating system managing file writes to optimize the time.

Comment: Another option is to intercept the `SIGINT` signal and flush the buffer before closing. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/.  Assuming that you're on linux.

Comment: @CHendrix *Another option is to intercept the `SIGINT` signal and flush the buffer before closing. thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code. Assuming that you're on linux.*  Ooof.  The only functions safe to call in a signal handler are those specifically marked as being async-signal-safe.  [See the Linux `signal` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for the list of async-signal-safe functions on Linux.  If the function isn't listed, it's not async-signal-safe.  Neither `printf()` (from your example) nor `fflush()` are async-signal-safe.

Answer (score 3):

You could set a custom handler for `SIGINT` in which you set a flag, and then exit gracefully whenever that flag is set.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

void handle_int(int sig)
{
  flag = 1;
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, handle_int); // intercept SIGINT

  while (!flag)
  {
    // do work ...
  }
  // cleanup, fflush, etc...
  return 0;
}
```

Note that calling `fflush` directly in the signal handler is unsafe.

The `// do work` part obviously should be relatively short, so that the `flag` is checked regularly throughout the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can use the `EVIOCGKEY ioctl` to check if a key is pressed and then `break` out of the `while (1)` loop.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int rdKey(int fd, int key) {//faster not to open file every time the function is called
//  const char *keyboard = "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd";
//  int fd = open(keyboard, O_RDONLY);
    char arr[(KEY_MAX+7)/8];
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
    ioctl(fd, EVIOCGKEY(sizeof(arr)), arr);
    return !!(arr[key/8] & (1<<(key % 8)));
}
```

You would pass a file descriptor for an input device like a keyboard and then either the key number or a macro from `input.h` like `KEY_A` for 'a' and it would return `1` if the key is  pressed and `0` if not.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider would be have the application `fork()` with the child process becoming the server and the parent remain attached to the terminal waiting for input with the two communicating through a socket or pipe.

Before doing the `fork()` the parent would create a socket or pipe which it will use to communicate with the child process. The user could then type commands into the parent process still attached to the terminal and the parent process would then echo commands to the child process through the socket or pipe.

The child would use `select()` and include the communication socket/pipe in the list of descriptors. So where as your code above uses only a single socket with the `read()` you would instead use a `select()` with both the socket shared by with the parent as well as the socket from the accept with a check to determine if there is a command from the parent waiting to be read or more server work to do. The child can then do any tidying up needed and exit cleanly with the parent doing a `wait()` for it to finish up and then the parent exits itself.

Sorry I don't have any code example handy. See the following stackoverflow for details about sockets and `select()`.

[Is it possible (and safe) to make an accepting socket non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861956/is-it-possible-and-safe-to-make-an-accepting-socket-non-blocking)

[c++ select async programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626854/c-select-async-programming)

[Asynchronous C client for a multiclient C server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729561/asynchronous-c-client-for-a-multiclient-c-server)

[How do I change a TCP socket to be non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543466/how-do-i-change-a-tcp-socket-to-be-non-blocking)

[working of fork in c language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210638/working-of-fork-in-c-language)